# Error in rviz tf2 tutorial

Tags: ros, rviz, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tf2 tutorial the following line is incorrect:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-turtle-tf2 ros-$ROS_DISTRO-turtle-tf2-tools ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf
```

because `ros-lunar-turtle-tf2-tools` doesn't exist, but `ros-lunar-tf2-tools` does. Just a naming error. So it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-turtle-tf2 ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf2-tools ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267765/error-in-rviz-tf2-tutorial/) by [xuelong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31396/xuelong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That does look like a typo. Can you link to the tutorial you're referring to? There isn't an 'rviz' tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuelong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31396/xuelong/) on 2017-08-01**:
Yep sorry, it's the first tf2 tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf2

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-08-01**:
Thanks. I've fixed it.